# What is the current state of Google support for JSON-LD schema formatting?

Tags: schema.org, rich-snippets, google-schemas, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

On Google's page [About Schema.org](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/schema-org) it is stated:

> JSON-LD is the newest and simplest markup format... Google is in the
>   process of adding JSON-LD support to more markup-powered features. So
>   far, JSON-LD is supported for all Knowledge Graph features, sitelink
>   search boxes, Event Rich Snippets, and Recipe Rich Snippets; Google
>   recommends the use of JSON-LD for those features. For the remaining
>   Rich Snippets types and breadcrumbs, Google recommends the use of
>   microdata or RDFa.

Yet on the page [Enabling Rich Snippets for Articles](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/articles) JSON-LD is shown in the examples as the first way to format article schema markup. Additionally, in the [Markup Helper Tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-helper/) article schema markup can be output as JSON-LD.

Seeing as one page does not list Rich Snippets for articles as a supported use of JSON-LD, and any uses not listed there are not recommended, one would think that it is not available for use. Then why is JSON-LD listed as an example, the first example no less, on the page about rich snippets for articles? A bit confusing.

I would like to begin using JSON-LD as the schema format for our site's articles, but only if it is certain that Google does in fact support its use. Could I get an official answer on the state of JSON-LD formatted schema markup support regarding article rich snippets from Google Support?

https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/articles

https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-helper/

Comment: I am not sure this is the forum to ask for an official Google response.

Comment: I do note Google says: (1) they currently have support for x, y, z. And (2) they intend to extend support to snippets. The use in the example seems to indicate this is something they intend to officially support. If you aren't marking up your articles in microdata or rdfa, you might like to add it anyway. It's extra bits, yes. But unless your publishing scholarly articles of enourmous length, duplicating it in json is not going to affect pageload by anything more than a few ms.

Comment: @TBB Google docs actually states that they monitor the tag "google-schemas" as the official way of requesting support.

They do intend to support it. What I need to know is what the **current** state of support is, specifically for article markup, as I intend to replace the old methods of including the data with JSON-LD formatted schema markup, as it is easier to dynamically populate and isn't horse-collared to the HTML directly.
The docs on this are not clear, not listing it explicitly but using it as a primary example for how to markup articles.

https://developers.google.com/schemas/support

Comment: Cool. Seems an appropriate forum then. Hopefully you get a response! :)

Comment: A thought just occurred - If you don't hear from Google, you might try asking if anyone has had success having article snippets displayed where they are only using json-ld markup? If you get a positive response then that that would also resolve your question, wouldn't it?.  Just a thought.